# Generate PDF from http request in Django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I need to generate pdf for reporting purpose. Front end will be sending me json list of list (dynamic, may have only one item, or N items) in the format of [title, file type, data] in http request.

```
[ ["Confusion Matrix", "img", "#image data in 64 bits encode"] , ["Graph1", "img", "#image data in 64 bits encode"] ]
```

In my view, after accepting the request, how should I convert them into http format one by one and append them into one big http template to generate the pdf? I was trying with django template but I wonder if there is any more elegant solution out there. The reason I am taking the file type in front end is due to image data will be encoded with 64 bits and text data will be stored in a txt in storage web service

Comment: Have you tried using ReportLab? The Django documentation suggests using that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/outputting-pdf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you could try `wkhtmltopdf` https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf. Usage is fairly simple. You should build the desired layout as a simple HTML template and give to `PDFTemplateView` which will then render pdf file as response.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^pdf/$', PDFTemplateView.as_view(template_name='my_template.html',
        filename='my_pdf.pdf'), name='pdf'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually have two questions: 1-how to handle json data in python, and 2-how to generate a pdf out of a template (correct me if I'm wrong)

I'm gonna answer the second question here. Search the web for the first one ;)

After json conversion, you can send the converted data to your html template and generate a pdf using [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit).

```
template = get_template("app_name/template.html")
context = Context({'data1':value1, 'data2':valu2})
html = template.render(context)
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

For generating PDF at request, you can also use WeasyPrint. You can follow this [Tutorial](https://micropyramid.com/blog/generate-pdf-files-from-html-in-django-using-weasyprint/)